# Not able to understand following Java lossy conversation from Int to Char

Tags: java, operator-overloading

Please go through the following class, it has a very simple method of converting a given string into all small letters.

My logic is to just add 32(ASCII value) in each letter of the string if it is a capital letter.

Now this addition can be done in two ways,

- 1. alphabet[i] = alphabet[i] + 32;
- 2. alphabet[i] += 32;

Now my question is that if I use line 1 to add 32 I get the following error while if I use line 2 for addition my class works, I would like to why this might be happening.

```
Line 8: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char
```

What is the difference between these two addition syntaxes?

```
class Solution {
    public String toLowerCase(String str) {
        char [] alphabet = str.toCharArray();

        for (int i=0; i<alphabet.length; i++) {
            // check if the alphabate is capital letter
            if (alphabet[i] >= 'A' && alphabet[i] <= 'Z') {
                //alphabet[i] = alphabet[i] + 32; --> Line 8: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char
                alphabet[i] += 32; // this line passes why?
            }
        }
        return new String(alphabet);

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, I want to ask why aren't you using `str.toLowerCase()`? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Well, nobody asked me this question ever. And why would any interviewer ask you to reimplement `toLowerCase()` functionality?

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz my guess is that this came up as part of an exercise.

Comment: Well, `alphabet[i] = (char) (alphabet[i] + 32);` this is the correct way to do it. Because when you do `char + int`, the smaller type is promoted to the larger type. So here `char` is promoted to `int` and it results in an `int` value which can't be directly assigned to `char`. That's why you need to cast it to `char`.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/to-lower-case/

Go through the discussions you will find many different ways of doing this thing. :) What's the fun if we are using library functions for everything.

Comment: In a real-world environment, you will always have to use libraries for such small functionalities. Because there is not much time to write everything from scratch. There is a reason why these methods are provided by the programming language itself.